# Camera calibration on android camera

Tags: calibration, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to calibrate the stereo cameras on the android camera, I'm running into problems.

1. I tried doing this in stereo webcams and done rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 right:=/my_stereo/right/image_raw left:=/my_stereo/left/image_raw left_camera:=**/dev/video2** right_camera:=**/dev/video1**

How would I do this using android phones when I cannot find to the set_camera_info?
This brings up the next where

2. I'm trying to advertise set_camera_info service to calibrate the cameras. One topic recommends camera_info_manager but I'm not entirely sure how its working.

Currently I have android ros publishing, and my ros master in laptop shows
/camera/stereo/left/camera_info
/camera/stereo/left/image_raw
/camera/stereo/left/image_raw/compressed
/camera/stereo/right/camera_info
/camera/stereo/right/image_raw
/camera/stereo/right/image_raw/compressed

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11462/camera-calibration-on-android-camera/) by [rhtmxhq8](https://answers.ros.org/users/1131/rhtmxhq8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rhtmxhq8](https://answers.ros.org/users/1131/rhtmxhq8/) on 2011-10-13**:
I'm not entirely so sure, its Android EVO3D, I want to know how to use the rosrun camera_info_manager, i'm guessing i need to know the driver.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-10-11**:
What camera driver are you running on the android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like your camera driver does not provide the set_camera_info service. Only few camera drivers do. In this case, you need to run cameracalibrator.py with this option:

```
--no-service-check
```

Once you are done calibrating, you have to find the file in which your camera driver stores its calibration information (the data published in camera_info) and edit it manually.

---

Originally posted by [sebsch](https://answers.ros.org/users/23/sebsch/) with karma: 790 on 2011-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0